# What is Captain America's religion?

Tags: marvel, movie, comics, captain-america, religion

In the Avengers movie this conversation occurs between Captain America and Black Widow:

> Natasha Romanoff: [discussing attacking Loki] They're basically gods.
>
> Steve Rogers: Ma'am, there's only one God, and I'm pretty sure he doesn't dress like that.

So it appears that Cap is at the very least a monotheist, but are there any confirmed specifics?

Comment: you mean it's not "America"?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### On Earth #19999

Marvel Cinema Earth's Captain America religion has not been explicitly stated, but it is mentioned he is a monotheist and most likely Christian.

### On Earth #616

The Captain America of the canon Marvel Earth #616 has been listed as [devoutly **Protestant**](http://www.adherents.com/lit/comics/CaptainAmerica.html). Images of Earth #616's Captain America engaged in religious activity are limited partially due to the ambiguous stance of comics and religion in the 1940's. When the 1960's came about the Captain was portrayed as staunch and upright with a limited understanding of modern culture and language.

> Captain America's religious affiliation was mentioned in Newsweek. (Steven Waldman and Michael Kress, "BeliefWatch: Good Fight", published in Newseek, cover-dated 19 June 2006, page 12)

### On Earth #1610

The Ultimates Captain America (Earth #1610) is also listed as and often depicted as devotely religious attending services every Sunday it's possible to do so.

[image: Earth 1610 Thor and Captain America argue]

Comment: You state he's a protestant, but I couldn't find any issue that states his religion specifically. Also you say Capt' America (of earth #616) is a protestant but you've got a picture form the ultimate's line. Whilst unlikely for the denominations to be different, it doesn't seem right that your using one for evidence of the other, when the two universes are different.

Comment: According to the (unofficial, fan-edited) Marvel wikia (citing _Captain America_ vol 1 #255 and/or _Captain America_ vol 7 # 11, neither of which I have access to) he's Irish Catholic.

Comment: @KutuluMike there's no such denomination as "Irish Catholic". Most (almost all) catholics who are Irish will be Roman Catholic.

Answer (score 14):

Captain America is certainly Christian, and most likely [Protestant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protestantism).

Whilst there is no evidence on the movie version of Captain America (from universe #199999) we can inform ourselves by looking to the comics:
I found this information on Captain's [Comic Book Religion page](https://www.comicbookreligion.com/index.php?c=11&Captain_America_Steve_Rogers), which led me [here](http://www.adherents.com/lit/comics/CaptainAmerica.html) and quotes the same [newsweek](http://web.archive.org/web/20060613084051/http://msnbc.msn.com/id/13249146/site/newsweek/) source as [Thaddeus](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/18106/3804).

Though I can find nowhere that explicitly states he is protestant, it doesn't seem like too much of a stretch.

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly certain he's Catholic, primarily because his parents Sarah and Joseph Rogers were Irish immigrants.  Statistically, they would have probably been Catholic, though of course there are plenty of Protestants in Northern Ireland.

I would say that James Buchanan Barnes would be Scottish, and therefore probably Presbyterian (Protestant) though likewise, there are Scots Catholics.

There seems to be an idea that both of them were orphans in a Catholic run orphanage, but I don't know where that comes from.

Comment: This is wildly assumptive. It's a bit like saying that because the population of Ireland is 51% female, Captain America is probably a woman.

Comment: @Valorum - not at all.  Movies exist in a "world of cliches".  if a character carries a handbag and minces, he's being telegraphed as "gay" or "camp".  (Obviously in the real world, he may not be.)  Darth Vader has the black clothes and is the bad guy.  Vivian dresses like a hooker, and she is one. It's normal in movies that Irish are drunk catholics, everyone "from San Francisco" is a gay dotcom owner, and so on.  Your point about "assumptions" would (of course) be true in the real world: in the MOVIE, everything about Captain America (starting with his name, for goodness sake),

Comment: .. points to him being the "typical" ("1950s") "all-American" boy.  So, he's Christian, Married, drives a pickup, lives in the suburbs, Was The Quarterback In High School and so on.  It's the whole point of the character.  Yes, there's a whacky tension between the fact that "in the Marvel universe, we have actual Thor, etc" and "Christianity" - but so what, it's a comic book.  All scifi movies have huge basic plot-confusions (hyperspace, time travel, etc), no worries there.

Comment: @Fattie - He's not married

Comment: Good grief.  He also doesn't drive a pickup truck.  You must see what I mean  :)  Cheers for now...

Comment: Given that 93% of the population at the time the character was created and into the 1970s was Catholic, that's a tad of a different probability. Also, probability given the initial conditions does not work that way.

Answer (score 0):

He's Catholic, he comes from an Irish Catholic family from the lower east side of Manhattan. Also in the movies Brooklyn seems to be the theme as it was exclusively Catholic and Jewish with Protestant Afro American communities.

Comment: Coming from a Catholic family [doesn't make you a Catholic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_former_Roman_Catholics#Atheism.2C_agnosticism.2C_or_non-religious).

Comment: @Valorum: Honestly, much like being Jewish, there's a degree to which it sticks to you based on heritage. And from a theological view, if you've been baptized, the most you can do is become a non-practicing Catholic (although, until Confirmation, you're not considered a full adult member of the Church because either someone else took your vows for you, or you weren't old enough to fully understand).

Comment: @FuzzyBoots You can definitely go from being a baptized/confirmed Catholic to being something else. I did, and I was told once that more Mormon converts (at least in that particular church) were former Catholics than were anything else.  Even if this answer is right, that he's from a Catholic family (was this explained somewhere?), Valorum's point is still valid.

Comment: @plutotheplanet: I think we may be discussing different perspectives on Catholic identities. :) Aside from theology, some people feel like being Catholic is like being Black or Jewish. You can disavow it, but it's part of who you are. But it's not really something I argue too heavily.