# Does Howard the Duck ever cross into Earth 616?

Tags: marvel, howard-the-duck

One of the oft-forgotten (possibly intentionally forgotten) facts about Howard the Duck is that he is technically a Marvel Comics character. It was always my understanding that he was only a parallel universe character.

His bio on [Marvel's website](http://marvel.com/universe/Howard_the_Duck), however is a bit unclear. It makes mention of teaming up with She-Hulk and staying with Generation X for a time, but does not specify which reality any of those events occurred in. It also specifically mentions Counter-Earth.

**Is there any canon instance of Howard the Duck ever crossing over into Earth-616?**

Comment: I thought all those *are* canon instances. Didn't Howard the Duck cross-over from Duckworld and has been stuck on 616 ever since?

Comment: @Shisa They might be; I haven't read anything with him in it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howard_the_Duck#Heroes_Reborn):

> Howard goes through several dimensions, apparently through the power of Man-Thing, who can now talk but does not understand this ability, and lands on a version of Duckworld where his parents are essentially Ward and June Cleaver, has a sister named Princess, and **is regarded as a hero because his activities on Earth-616** were recognized by Duckworld's version of Reed Richards.

And also this page lists his exploits in [Marvel Zombies 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Zombies_5) where he is also listed as an Earth-616 character.

Comment: What a day! Howard the Duck, Marvel Zombies and even a [Yahweh](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14409/religion-in-the-marvel-universe/64843#64843) character...

Comment: Is "his activities" referring to the "Squished Earth" thing with She-Hulk or the stuff with Man-Thing?

Comment: @phantom42 - I don't know, looks like a general comment on everything he's done on Earth-616 up to then.

Comment: There was a duckworld Reed Richards? Was there a duckworld Ben Grimm too?

Answer (score -1):

### Howard the Duck shows up in a post-credit scene of Guardians of The Galaxy.

Although this is not on earth, this still proves he is officially part of MCU and most certainly can cross over into earth.

Comment: This is not [Earth-616](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Earth-616), which the question specifically asked about..

Comment: That scene looks like "Knowhere" to me too.

Comment: That scene is also from Guardians of the Galaxy *1*, not 2.

Comment: @phantom42 fixed

Comment: You didn't fix or change anything that even relates to Earth-616. The MCU is an entirely different universe, and regardless of whether or not he can go to Earth in the MCU has no bearing on whether or not he *has* crossed over to Earth-616.

Comment: @F1Krazy to be fair, he also shows up in Guardians 2. But yes, this scene is from the first movie.